# QT Installer framework: How to use -n option in binary creator for online installer

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I want create online installer without data embedded in it. Documentation says "Use the -n parameter of the binarycreator tool and only add the root component to the installer". What do you mean by root component. I am using below code to execute binarycreator tool.

```
Process *build = new QProcess(this);
QStringList arguments;
QString file_name = m_parent->GetOutPutPageInstance()->GetFileName();
arguments << "--online-only" << "-c" << ConfFilePath << file_name;
build->execute(bincreatorExe,arguments);
```

when i provide repository directory it works fine. But i dont want to embed the data init. installer should download it from online repository.

Answer (score 0):

`How can i have two different config file at same time?`

A config file isn't needed to install offline or online...

It is possible to install offline by including the files to install in the ressources (use QRessource .qrc) or online by downloading them using QtNetwork.

> But it doesn't make sense to have both *at the same time*.
>
> Why would you need to download files that you already have...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figure out what i  need to do.

Comment: Basically this installer is for client to distribute. They run this to install software which are there on my server. This way it reduces the size of executable.